# How to use react router to use Hash in URLs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

i am new to react and facing a problem. I have a page which contain two tabs. I want to make a hash URL so that it can redirect to corresponding tabs on the basis of url hash. Similarly when i open the page and change a tab, url also updates. Kindly answer in a detailed way as i am new to this and donot know about professional terms.
Moreover i am also bound to use react router for this.
Note: I am using typescript in case it changes something for my solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls update your code or image

Answer (score 2):

**HashRouter** uses a hash symbol in the URL, which has the effect of all subsequent URL path content being ignored in the server request (ie you send `"www.mywebsite.com/#/person/id"` the server gets `"www.mywebsite.com"`. As a result, the server will return the pre `#` URL response, and then the post `#` path will be handled by parsed by your client-side react application.

*example code* :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } 
            from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Home from './component/home'; 
import About from './component/about'; 
import Contact from './component/contact'; 
import './App.css'; 

class App extends Component { 
render() { 
    return ( 
        <Router> 
            <div className="App"> 
                <ul className="App-header"> 
                <li> 
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <Link to="/about">About Us</Link> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <Link to="/contact"> 
                        Contact Us 
                    </Link> 
                </li> 
                </ul> 
                <Switch> 
                <Route exact path='/'
                    component={Home}> 
                </Route> 
                <Route exact path='/about'
                    component={About}> 
                </Route> 
                <Route exact path='/contact'
                    component={Contact}> 
                </Route> 
                </Switch> 
            </div> 
        </Router> 
    ); 
} 
} 

export default App;
```